# Timediff in mysql not returning result

Tags: mysql

Im running this query:

```
Select timediff(curtime(),c.approved) From C c WHERE 1=1
```

and Im getting no result but in my db I have :

```
id, approved, Type, file, firstRequest, lastRequest, paymentMethod_id
43, 2012-11-18 14:33:55, CC_Copy, , 2012-11-18 14:33:55, , 1
```

Comment: What's your table definition? What's the type of the "approved" column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff):

> TIMEDIFF() returns expr1 – expr2 expressed as a time value. expr1 and expr2 are time or date-and-time expressions, but **both must be of the same type**.

You're feeding in a time (`curtime()`) and a datetime (`approved`). Change it to

```
select timediff(curtime(), time(approved)) ...
```

instead, assuming `approved` is a datetime type, and not char/varchar.